# Force iContact signup form not to redirect to a different page

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms

I'm trying to make this simple iContact form not to redirect to either success page or error page. I just want my visitors to submit the form without being redirected away from the page or reloading the page.

I've been looking around but I couldn't solve this. Here is my iContact form code (I replaced my account info):

```
<style>
.link,
.link a,
.signupframe
{
    color: #000000;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    }
    .link,
    .link a {
        text-decoration: none;
        }
    .signupframe {
        border: 1px solid #000000;
        background: #ffffff;
        }
.signupframe .required {
    font-size: 10px;
    }
</style>
<form method="post" action="https://app.icontact.com/icp/signup.php" name="icpsignup" id="icpsignupAAAA" accept-charset="UTF-8" onsubmit="return verifyRequiredAAAA();" >
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://www.icontact.com/www/signup/thanks.html">
<input type="hidden" name="errorredirect" value="http://www.icontact.com/www/signup/error.html">

<div id="SignUp">
<table width="260" class="signupframe" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" align="right">
        <span class="required">*</span> Email
      </td>
      <td align="left">
        <input type="text" name="fields_email">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <input type="hidden" name="listid" value="42379">
    <input type="hidden" name="specialid:42379" value="O6IC">

    <input type="hidden" name="clientid" value="954091">
    <input type="hidden" name="formid" value="4616">
    <input type="hidden" name="reallistid" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="doubleopt" value="0">
    <tr>
      <td> </td>
      <td><span class="required">*</span> = Required Field</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> </td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">

var icpForm4616 = document.getElementById('icpsignupAAAA');

if (document.location.protocol === "https:")

    icpForm4616.action = "https://app.icontact.com/icp/signup.php";
function verifyRequired4616() {
  if (icpForm4616["fields_email"].value == "") {
    icpForm4616["fields_email"].focus();
    alert("The Email field is required.");
    return false;
  }


return true;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post the form with AJAX instead on submit. use the same onSubmit call as above, just post it by AJAX and then return false instead (form never posts to the action attribute value). In the example below Im using the jQuery library for ajax functions, so if you dont have it you must download and install it...

REMOVE your javascript at the bottom, then add this instead. Make sure you have downloaded and installed the jQuery file in your FTP. Also add correctly the HTML structure with html, head and body tags: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.1

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function verifyRequiredAAAA()
 { 

   var eReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/; // regex to check valid email
   var email = $('input[name="fields_email"]').val();
   if (email == "") {
      $('input[name="fields_email"]').focus();
      alert("The Email field is required.");
      return false;
   } else if (!eReg.test(email)) {
      $('input[name="fields_email"]').focus();
      alert("The Email address is incorrect.");
      return false;
   } else {
      $.post("https://app.icontact.com/icp/signup.php",
            $("#icpsignupAAAA").serialize(), function(data){
                  $('#successcontainer').html(data);
            });
            return false;
   }
 } 

</script>
```

Then in your HTML put a container for a potential success message:

```
<div id="successcontainer"></div>
```

(the message here comes from your PHP script (the PHP should return something...))

Change your FORM tag to:

```
 <form id="icpsignup4616" onsubmit="return verifyRequired4616()" accept-charset="UTF-8" name="icpsignup" action="" method="post">
```

You could also for instance remove the complete form, if you in the success function (after the row with successcontainer) add

```
$("#icpsignupAAAA").hide();
```

Comment: If you return the form onSubmit as false the form never takes you away, but instead let jQuery post data and get a reply from the PHP-script.

Comment: thanks for your answer, would you please explain to me a little bit how to do that, and how to embedded the code you provided in the main code, as i'm a total beginner and have no idea about AJAX, thanks.

Comment: would you please explain to me how to return the form onSubmit as false, thanks.

Comment: just make the return the form onSubmit as false, and the code stopped working.

Comment: @Michael I just edited and clearified this a bit, hope it helps!

Comment: first of, thanks for your quick response, well, i know that your post should solve this thing, but i tried to make it work a lot and i failed, i'm a total beginner to this, this is the link [link](http://bsblgroup.info/signupform.html) for the page i'm trying to make it work on, it's just a test page, i would really appreciate it if you could tell me what's wrong with the code, and how should it be, thanks

Comment: @Michael First of all it helps to have the HTML use the standard markup format, that mean it need to follow the principle with a leading <html> tag, then use <head> and </head> followed by <body> and ending with </body> and finally </html>. For your use I would put all the javascript AND style things in the <head> section and then the form in the <body> part. Furthermore you have not downloaded and installed the jQuery library. Get it from http://www.jquery.com and FTP it to your hosting and check the path and filename (src="/js/jquery.1.7.2.min.js")...

Comment: @Michael I also put there a function that validates and checks so also that the email is not only empty but also has a correct syntax.

Comment: just added the HTML standard markup format, deleted the javascript at the bottom, installed jQuery, and it still not working, what is it i did wrong?[link](http://bsblgroup.info/signupform.html)

Comment: @Michael You can only have the js function once. So remove the first javascript part, as the other is complete. Also check I did a little update above, changed "success" text to "function" in the post part of js.

Comment: did all the changes, and it now redirecting more than ever :(, i'm sorry i keep bothering you [link](http://bsblgroup.info/signupform.html)

Comment: just edit the form tag, and it worked just fine although there is no thank you message but i doesn't matter, i owe you big time, many thanks, it wouldn't work without your help:)

Comment: @Michael Great that it finally works! But the thank you message is the thing that is returned from the PHP script. If you dont have thet possibility then you could add a message to be sent from the success handler. Change $('#successcontainer').html(data); to $('#successcontainer').html('Your success message here'); Great also if you set this answer to the correct answer here...

Comment: I am confused how @Michael answered can work despite cross-domain restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

change the value in these lines to the url you want it to redirect to on success or error.

```
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://www.icontact.com/www/signup/thanks.html">
<input type="hidden" name="errorredirect" value="http://www.icontact.com/www/signup/error.html">
```

Comment: i don't want it to redirect any way from my site, i just want it to submit without redirecting anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be impossible to do what you want due to cross-domain (CORS) restrictions. If you would try to use the jQuery solution as was suggested, you would get something along these lines:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://app.icontact.com/icp/signup.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access.`

**UPDATE**

Thr request does seem to reach iContact servers. However, beside that error in the console, the AJAX request is considered to be failed.